# SSL Certificate add failed, Cannot create a file when that file already exists. on azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, iis-bindings

Post adding the HTTPS binds in azure devops along with certificate thumbprint I'm getting below error:

[image: Error on running the pipeline on azure devops]

Here, I'm trying to add my existing certificate to new IIS application.

Please let me know the steps as I'm new to azure devops.